# Get last comment of all posts in one category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, postgresql-9.3

Comment belongs to Post.
Post belongs to Category.

How would I get a collection of every lastly updated comment for each post, all belonging to one single category?

I've tried this but it just gives me one post:

```
category.posts.joins(:comments).order('updated_at DESC').first
```

**Update**

What I want is to fetch *one* commment per post, the last updated comment for each post.

Comment: What database are you using? Rails doesn't support this well so we need to go to a lower level to make it work nicely.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails doesn't do this particularly well, especially with Postgres which forbids the obvious solution (as given by @Jon and @Deefour).

Here's the solution I've used, translated to your example domain:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :most_recent, -> { joins(
    "INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (post_id) post_id,id FROM comments ORDER BY post_id,updated_at DESC,id
    ) most_recent ON (most_recent.id=comments.id)"
  )}
  ...
```

(`DISTINCT ON` is a Postgres extension to the SQL standard so it won't work on other databases.)

Brief explanation: the `DISTINCT ON` gets rid of all the rows except the first one for each `post_id`. It decides which row the first one is by using the `ORDER BY`, which has to start with `post_id` and then orders by `updated at DESC` to get the most recent, and then `id` as a tie-breaker (usually not necessary).

Then you would use it like this:

```
Comment.most_recent.joins(:post).where("posts.category_id" => category.id)
```

The query it generates is something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM comments
  INNER JOIN posts ON (posts.id=comments.post_id)
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (post_id) post_id,id FROM comments ORDER BY post_id,updated_at DESC,id
  ) most_recent ON (most_recent.id=comments.id)
WHERE
  posts.category_id=#{category.id}
```

Single query, pretty efficient. I'd be ecstatic if someone could give me a less complex solution though!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a collection of every last updated **Comment**, you need to base your query on `Comment`, not `Category`.

```
Comment.joins(:post).
        where("posts.category_id = ?", category.id).
        group("posts.id").
        order("comments.updated_at desc")
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're basically asking for is a `has_many :through` association.

Try setting up your `Category` model something like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, through: :posts
end
```

Then you can simply do this to get the last 10 updated comments:

```
category.comments.order('updated_at DESC').limit(10)
```

You could make this more readable with a named scope on your `Comment` model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :recently_updated, -> { order('updated_at DESC').limit(10) }
end
```

Giving you this query to use to get the same 10 comments:

```
category.comments.recently_updated
```

### EDIT

So, a similar solution for what you actually wanted to ask for, however it requires you to approach your associations from the `Comment` end of things.

First of all, set up an association on `Comment` so that it has knowledge of its `Category`:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_one :category, through: :post
end
```

Now you can query your comments like so:

```
Comment.order('updated_at desc').joins(:post).where('posts.category' => category).group(:post_id)
```

Somewhat long-winded, but it works.

Comment: Is it possible with this structure to get one comment (the last updated) for each post? (Sorry if I haven't been clear enough on this.)

Comment: You're right - you really weren't very clear on that. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Jon SQL `group by` returns aggregates not rows of the table. Unfortunately the real solution is a lot more complex than `.order.group`.

Comment: True - my bad. Perhaps you can't avoid a mess of a query starting from `Comment` in this case.

Comment: That should be better.

Comment: which is exactly what I suggested :)

Comment: I think that will only work in MySQL. Postgres will give an error, the columns `must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`.

Answer (score 0):

`.first` is grabbing only one for you. The first one to be exact. So drop the `.first`. So instead do:

`category.posts.joins(:comments).order('updated_at DESC')`

Comment: That is just returning all posts.. :/

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood you. I just upvoted the correct answer above.